# Paid Training courses for SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013

I want to start a new SharePoint 2013 project, but I did not find a class-room training centres which give SharePoint training courses for 2013 version in my country. So instead of this I am trying to find paid online training courses which will be more convenient and professional than the free online courses I am currently reading. So can anyone recommend –from previous experience – what are the best online training courses to take, in general I need the training to cover these main areas:-

1. Developing internal & external application using SharePoint 2013.
2. Using web parts and doing customization for SharePoint 2013.
3. Administration tasks.
4. Deploying SharePoint on IIS and going live...

Thanks in advance for any help.
BR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without doubt the best I have seen and used is [Pluralsight](http://www.pluralsight.com/training) they have specific SP2013 courses here [SharePoint 2013 Developer Ramp-Up](http://www.pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/cpt-sp2013-dev-ramp-part1)

Hope this helps.

S

Comment: thanks for the link, i remember that i have attended online training for asp.net MVC and these training was offered for free at Microsoft site. But i think for the SharePoint i have to pay for it , am i right? and well i get chances to ask questions for the author and attend other videos conferences?

Comment: Yeah Pluralsight is a paid for service, you can get a 15 day trial though to test out the courses...

Comment: I just register with Pluralsight, and the videos seems interesting , but if i make a simple comparison there are 33 videos for SharePoint 2010 while there is  only 11 videos for SharePoint 2013. So as in my case I am new to SharePoint in general so does this mean that I cannot rely on the 11 videos offered for SP 2013 and I have to rely on other resources or even on SP 2010 videos? I am interested only on developing SharePoint 2013 not installing it and doing other administration tasks.
BR

Comment: I just looked and there's currently about 43 hours of SharePoint 2013 developer training. I also looked at the planner and there are another 4 courses (approx 20 hours) currently in development. Each course has a discussions page where you can ask questions of the author and other members of the site. (Full disclosure - I am an author for Pluralsight)

Comment: Just to update this regarding PluralSight. There are currently (Oct, 15, 2013) 90 courses on SharePoint and more than 17 of those are SP 2013 specific. Topics now range from installation and administration to development and even cover the MCSE certifications (i.e. ops not dev).

Answer (score 0):

I've used Pluralsight and there are some decent courses on there. They use a subscription-based pricing model. On the other hand, sites like Udemy offer online training using the pay-per-course model (but you get lifetime access once paid). I published one out there myself a while back on [timer job development for SharePoint 2013](https://www.udemy.com/developing-custom-timer-jobs-for-sharepoint-2013/) because it was a concept a lot of developers weren't well versed on, and I liked that Udemy gave students lifetime access.